# How run the Volttron playbook install-platform.yml with Ansible

Tags: ansible, volttron

First I install the Volttron recipes via

```bash
ansible-galaxy install git+https://github.com/volttron/volttron-ansible.git
```

Then Verify the install

```bash
ansible-galaxy list

# /Users/username/.ansible/roles
 - volttron-ansible, (unknown version)
```

Then I setup the host and try to run the playbook

```bash
ansible-playbook -K \
                 -i $TEST_HOST \
                 playbooks/install-platform.yml
    # TEST_HOST is the path the to host file
```

And I get the error:

```bash
ERROR! the role 'volttron.deployment.set_defaults' was not found in /Users/username/Development/iot/experiment-volttron/playbooks/roles:/Users/username/.ansible/roles/volttron-ansible:/Users/username/Development/iot/experiment-volttron/playbooks

The error appears to be in '/Users/username/Development/iot/experiment-volttron/playbooks/install-platform.yml': line 6, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  roles:
    - volttron.deployment.set_defaults
      ^ here
```

The Host connects correctly - and the roles seemed to be installed at `/Users/username/.ansible/roles/volttron-ansible` correctly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You installed a role (as role is the default object for ansible galaxy if ommited). I'm rather positive that the documentation for volttron-ansible is wrong. Since you want to get a collection, you want to run `ansible-galaxy collection install git+https://github.com/volttron/volttron-ansible.git` which will install the role in the corresponding `volttron.deployment` namespace AND the custom modules. Note that this collection does not respect best dev practices (i.e. the playbook are not in the `playbook` subdir and cannot be used with the corresponding namespace from anywhere).

Comment: Note: I pushed [quickNdirty PR](https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron-ansible/pull/21#pullrequestreview-1135140697) on the github repo to fix this issue. Apparently, this has raised authors attention as [an other PR](https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron-ansible/pull/24) fixing the documentation and relocating the playbooks (plus other fixes) was proposed a bit later.